# Automapper to XML serialization producing unwanted parent XML elements

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper, xml-serialization, ienumerable

I'm using automapper to map out part of my game to an XML file so that I can export it:

cfg.CreateMap()
    .ForMember(d => d.RoomType, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.GetRoomType()))

For some reason that I cannot figure out, it is adding a parent element to the XML like this:

```
  <RoomType>
    <RoomType monster="Random">X_Y001</RoomType>
    <RoomType monster="Random">X_Y003</RoomType>
    <RoomType monster="Random">X_Y005</RoomType>
  </RoomType>
```

I don't want the XML structure to look like that, I just want the elements like this:

```
    <RoomType monster="Random">X_Y001</RoomType>
    <RoomType monster="Random">X_Y003</RoomType>
    <RoomType monster="Random">X_Y005</RoomType>
```

Here is the method GetRoomType:

```
public static IEnumerable<RoomType> GetRoomType(this DungeonRoom room)
{

   var customType = room.Monsters
           .Where(e => e.Treasure.Category.IsActive);

   if (room.RoomType?.MonsterType == null) yield break;

   if (room.RoomType.MonsterType.StartsWith("X_Y"))
   {
       yield return new RoomType(room.RoomType.MonsterType);
   }

   foreach (PageTreasure pe in customType)
   {
      if (customType == null) yield break;

      if (RoomLookupByTypeId.ContainsKey(pe.Treasure.Id))
           yield return RoomLookupByTypeId[pe.Treasure.Id];
      }
   }
}
```

And here is the RoomLookupByTypeId() method:

```
public static readonly IDictionary<Int32, RoomType> RoomLookupByTypeId =
    new Dictionary<Int32, RoomType> {
        {373, new RoomType("X_Y001")},
        {488, new RoomType("X_Y002")},
        {467, new RoomType("X_Y003")},
        {238, new RoomType("X_Y004")},
        {756, new RoomType("X_Y005")}
    };
```

And here is the class that is being mapped out to XML:

```
public class RoomType
{
    [XmlText]
    public String TypeId { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("monster")]
    public String Monster
    {
        get { return "Random"; }
        set { throw new NotSupportedException("Computed property, setter only exists for XmlSerializer"); }
    }

    public RoomType() { }

    public RoomType(String Id)
    {
        TypeId = Id;
    }

}
```

And this is an example result:

```
  <RoomType>
    <RoomType monster="Random">X_Y001</RoomType>
    <RoomType monster="Random">X_Y003</RoomType>
    <RoomType monster="Random">X_Y005</RoomType>
  </RoomType>
```

So the data is correct, but it's adding that opening and closing `<RoomType>` which it does not need.

I'm not sure why it's doing that.

At first, I thought it was because GetRoomType() was returning something other than 'null', but I added 'yield break' to stop it from returning anything if it finds a null.

So I'm at a loss.  I have no idea why it's doing this.

Does anyone see anything that could be causing it?

Thanks!

Comment: If the parent was `<RoomTypes>` would that be acceptable?

Comment: Well the actual parent is <Room>, and <RoomType> and a bunch of other elements are children.  It is only the RoomType mapping that is causing this issue. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think having <RoomType> directly in <Room> is strictly XML compliant.

Comment: @Neil you are probably right, but this is just for personal use.  The other elements being mapped work fine. It's just this one that is being pesky. :)

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's for personal use, XML tools try to stop you doing things that are not compliant.    Try putting `[XmlElement("RoomTypes")]` on the collection you are serialising.

Comment: @Neil do you mean on the public class RoomType?  Thanks!

Comment: No, on the collection you are serialising, which I think is `RoomLookupByTypeId`.  You don't show the serialisation code, but I assume it's just something like `XmlSerializer.Serialize(theObject)`.